# Next/Apollo: How to correctly update apollo cache if the relevant query was run in getInitialProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, next.js, react-apollo

I'm using nextjs and apollo (with react hooks). I am trying to update the user object in the apollo cache (I don't want to refetch). What is happening is that the user seems to be getting updated in the cache just fine but the user object that the component uses is not getting updated. Here is the relevant code:

The page:

```
// pages/index.js

...

const Page = ({ user }) => {
  return <MyPage user={user} />;
};


Page.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  const { apolloClient } = context;
  const user = await apolloClient.query({ query: GetUser }).then(({ data: { user } }) => user);

  return { user };
};

export default Page;
```

And the component:

```
// components/MyPage.jsx

...

export default ({ user }) => {
  const [toggleActive] = useMutation(ToggleActive, {
    variables: { id: user.id },
    update: proxy => {
      const currentData = proxy.readQuery({ query: GetUser });

      if (!currentData || !currentData.user) {
        return;
      }

      console.log('user active in update:', currentData.user.isActive);

      proxy.writeQuery({
        query: GetUser,
        data: {
          ...currentData,
          user: {
            ...currentData.user,
            isActive: !currentData.user.isActive
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });

  console.log('user active status:', user.isActive);

  return <button onClick={toggleActive}>Toggle active</button>;
};
```

When I continuously press the button, the console log in the update function shows the user active status as flipping back and forth, so it seems that the apollo cache is getting updated properly. However, the console log in the component always shows the same status value.

I don't see this problem happening with any other apollo cache updates that I'm doing where the data object that the component uses is acquired in the component using the `useQuery` hook (i.e. not from a query in `getInitialProps`).

Comment: Did you try using useEffect in the second component as componentWillUpdate ? it will re-render the MyPage as soon a the props changes ...

Comment: @Afsanefda that doesn't work because `user` is not changing in the props, so the useEffect callback never gets triggered. Unless you are suggesting I listen for the `user` in the apollo cache to change? it seems weird that i should have to do that...

Comment: I haven't tried apollo before but it seems your user data is not going to change because getInitialProps executes once before the page is loaded so the user value will be set and won't change!  If you could provide a code box sample maybe I could help you!

Comment: Did you solve this problem?